# Function that does nothing in Lua

Tags: python, lua

I've recently started learning Lua. The only other programming language I have some experience in is Python. In Python there is the "pass" function that does nothing. I was wondering what the equivalent (if any) of this would be in Lua.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Python, `pass` is an important placeholder for incomplete code. It must exist because Python doesn't allow empty code blocks. Stuff like `if` statements, loops etc. require a body, so you place a `pass` there when you want to leave the implementation for later.

```
def myfunction(a, b, c):
    pass # im doing this later
```

In Lua, however, this is not necessary. It is perfectly fine to `end` an `if` or a `function` without including any body, so there is no need for a `pass` in Lua.

```
function myfunction(a, b, c)
    -- im doing this later
end
```

Comment: Technically `pass` isn't necessary in Python either, since you can always use a literal expression statement. And in the case of a function definition, a string literal becomes the docstring for the function, and it's often useful to write those before the code anyway…

Comment: Well thats one way to workaround it, but its not quite the same thing.

Comment: Sure, it's just that it's often the _right_ way to work around it, in the specific case of functions, which is why I thought it was worth a comment.

Answer (score 2):

Leave your conditional empty by doing this

`if <condition> then end`

Comment: Even simpler, an empty block: `do end`